# Github post commit trigger build in Hudson with security enabled

Tags: authentication, hudson, github

Github has no problem with triggering a build in Hudson with security turned off because the build is a public URL.  But I'd like to be able to have logins required on Hudson so that people can't arbitrarily build.  I tried looking for a HTTP basic auth method so I can include the credentials in the URL itself, but couldn't find anything like that.  Has anyone used Hudson with Github and run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem with subversion. I didn't find a solution. So Hudson is querying subverion for changes every 5 minutes and only builds if changes are detected.

Answer (score 0):

Kohsuke commented on this in a bug recently - [HUDSON-1555](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-1555)

There is a feature for a build token, which will allow a build to be triggered without authentication.   The comment in HUDSON-1555, however, indicates this feature is deprecated.   If the UI for the build token is still around, it should solve your problem.